# Several errors while trying to run Spark with python 3

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run spark using `pyspark` on `python 3` with `ubuntu 18.04`, however, I'm getting a bunch of different errors that I don't know how to handle. I'm using `Java 10 jdk` and my `JAVA_HOME` variable is already set.

this is the code I'm trying to run on `python`:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext



sc = SparkContext(appName="PysparkStreaming")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)   #Streaming will execute in each 3 seconds
lines = ssc.textFileStream('/home/mabarberan/Escritorio/prueba spark/')  #'log/ mean directory name
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and these are the errors I'm getting:

```
/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/bin/python /home/mabarberan/Descargas/carpeta.py
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-06-21 12:53:07 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2018-06-21 12:53:13 ERROR PythonRunner:91 - Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 176, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

I can't paste all the error code here, but this is what comes next:

```
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 176, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

    2018-06-21 12:53:13 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-06-21 12:53:13 ERROR JobScheduler:91 - Error running job streaming job 1529578392000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 65, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 171, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1375, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 1013, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mabarberan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 176, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have googled the errors and saw them individually occurring to other people, but seems I have all of them in the same time, I tried some fixes I found on the web but they didn't seem to work, so I'm stuck. I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are starting master with anaconda python and workers are using default python. You can remove anaconda path from .bashrc or set PYSPARK_PYTHON and SPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON variables in spark-env to python path you want to use.
For examples add  lines below to $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export SPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: hey @hamza tuna, thank you for your answer. I already got that fix from the internet, tried it, but still having the same issue.

Comment: here are my env. variables in .bashrc:

`#spark

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export IPYTHON=1

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython3

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3

export SPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I dont know how important anaconda but i removed anaconda path line from .bashrc and it solved.